# Dynamic validation method name

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I need to validate a textbox based on the validation rule selected by the admin through a dropdown list. ex:

```
  $('<select/>').attr('id', 'SelectOption2_[]' + i)
                  .attr('name','SelectVal[]')
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('......To validate choose an option......') )
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('No validation') )
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('Validate_as_a_date') ) 
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('Validate_as_an_address') )
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('validate_as_an_e-mail_address') )
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('Validate_as_numbers_only') )
                  .append( $('<option/>').text('Validate_as_letters_only ') )
                  .addClass('selectbx')
                  .appendTo($div);
```

These are the options given to the the admin. This select box is referred to a textbox. So for each textbox admin is giving a validation rule where later it will be checked against the value entered by a  user.

After giving the validation rule by the admin I store the rule(Ex:Validate as a date, etc ) in the database. So the value which will be entered later by the user will be checked against the validation rule given by the admin.

So to do this, the validation method name should be changed accordingly. Is this scenario possible to do?

Comment: which validation you are going to use ? if javascript then, is it jquery validation engine ?

Comment: If the selected option is 'Validate as an address' when data is entered by the user I m going to call a pre defined method called Validate_as_an_addres(). Likewise method will be selected accordingly at the moment of entering data based on validating rule given by the admin.

Comment: Yes. This scenario is absolutely feasible. I would suggest while generating the markup for the final user. Add a custom attribute to each textbox depending upon the validation rule selected by the admin like:

`<input data-validation-type="Validate_as_a_date" />`

Then when the form is being submitted call the validate method & for each field in the form access the `data-validation-type` attribute & call the function accordingly.

Comment: :) K vikram thank you so much for the help.. Got an idea. Will go through that. :)